# error creating ipa

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, certificate

I tried to follow this video to make an ipa 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRhtsnFB0bM
but I have an error when I want to make Product > Archive

> [BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't
>   match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

It's the first time that I do that so I don't really know how it works, but I think it's a certificate problem. I made the app for someone. I downloaded his certificate from his account in developer.apple.com, what shall I do with it? Shall I make something in xcode to add it?

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to revoke the previous provisioning profiles in his
   account..(if you can get the previous person keychain files ..that
   get that and install in your keychain..compiling will be successful)
2. make a new distribution certificate using keychain in your mac
3. and then make a new distribution profile using that distribution
   certificate..then you will be able to compile using that profile.

Comment: what do you mean by if you can get the previous person keychain files ..that get that and install in your keychain..compiling will be successful ? i can download the old certificate ... can you explain please i am newbie

Comment: the reason you are not able to compile is that the present provisioning profile might have been made on a distribution certificate someone else made.....that certificate is not present in your keychain..if you can get that values from the other person..install it in your keychain..the app will compile again

Answer (score 0):

I get this error all the time since I use the same scheme for testing as I do for distro. You will have to go into your build settings for the project and the target and set the code signing back to iPhone Developer. Clean your settings and rebuild. That should do the trick.

Comment: This is assuming you just want to test... if you plan to Archive for distro... then you will need to update your certificates... which I can direct you to as well. Apple provisioning is the biggest drawback to iOS dev IMO. But once you figure it out, you'll be set.